# What is the difference between ASPNetCoreModule and ASPNetCoreModuleV2?

Tags: asp.net-core

I would like to know the difference between ASPNetCoreModule and ASPNetCoreModuleV2, when to use each of them in which scenario.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

- `ASPNetCoreModule` ("version 1") is the IIS Module that enables IIS to run ASP.NET Core 1.x and 2.x applications when they're running in .NET Core

  - ASP.NET Core 1.x and 2.x (but not ASP.NET Core 3.x and later) [can alternatively run on top of .NET Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51066369/asp-net-core-2-1-on-full-net-framework),  instead of .NET Core, in which case you can use IIS' built-in CLR pipeline without the need for `ASPNetCoreModule`.
  - Version 1 was discontinued and [removed from the ASP.NET GitHub repo in January 2019](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/commit/1ecc8dd9c691f410c3aed85417db75fe50b31032#diff-54519d7cd867fb07d7e96dd65385bce7f3f7647bac3aa66ad2f7a34120fe17f6). The only reason you would be using V1 today is if you're still running an ASP.NET Core 1.x application.

    - Which you *should not be doing* anyway.
- `ASPNetCoreModuleV2` supports ASP.NET Core 2.0 and later (including ASP.NET Core 3.x, .NET 5, .NET 6, etc). It also supports more features than V1 (such as custom offline messages).

> when to use each of them in which scenario.

Here's a flowchart:

- Are you looking to run your ASP.NET Core application in IIS (*without running on the .NET Framework*)?

  - Yes:

    - Are you targeting ASP.NET Core 1.x?

      - Yes <sub>(you masochist)</sub>

        - Use `ASPNetCoreModule` (V1) and update to ASP.NET Core 3.1 LTSB pronto.
      - No

        - Use `ASPNetCoreModuleV2`
    - Are you targeting ASP.NET Core 2.x, ASP.NET Core 3.x, .NET 5 or .NET 6?

      - Yes

        - Use `ASPNetCoreModuleV2`
      - No

        - Then this entire StackOverflow question is irrelevant to you
  - No

    - You don't need `ASPNetCoreModule` nor `ASPNetCoreModuleV2`

In short: there is **no  reason** to be using `ASPNetCoreModule` ("V1") today.

---

#### A note on the *actual differences* between V1 and V2:

I quickly delved through the source-code of the last version of the V1 module before it was removed from the repo, and compared it to V2...

The singular main difference is that V1 can only run as a simple request *proxy* that forwards the HTTP requests from IIS to a child process (`YourAspNetCoreApp.exe`), which is to say it *only* supports out-of-process hosting of ASP.NET Core applications. Whereas V2 supports running ASP.NET Core *in-process*, with numerous benefits.

A negative consequence of using out-of-proc hosting means that when using V1 you won't get `RequestAborted` notifications, and you can't make use of new HTTP/2 or HTTP/3 functionality from within your ASP.NET code.

Comment: My IIS shows both.. how do I go about removing ASPNetCoreModule (V1) from it ?

Comment: @joedotnot What do you mean by "My IIS shows both"? **Where** are you seeing it? as for removing it, haven't you looked in the Add/Remove Programs control panel?

Comment: My IIS shows both means "in IIS Manager itself". Go to top node in tree (root / server), Modules icon, double-click, there are 2 ASPNetCoreModules, one for V1 and V2 - as your answer says NO REASON to use V1 I want to remove it because it is installed on my "server".  ( I don't think it's related to Add/Remove programs, it was installed when I installed dotnet core preview 1.x, I am even struggling to remove this preview ) EDIT Ok, I can easily right click on that line, and Remove.

Comment: The flowchart is missing the fact that you can use ANCMv2 module to pass socket connections directly to a standalone process. This pass-through allows you to run any web server you like, but requires a startup script that runs a local web server. E.g. a Python Flask app served via waitress.

Comment: @MarkZ. Interesting, I didn't know that - do you have a reference to the docs on that? (But hang on - surely you don't even need ANCMv2 for that, you could use the IIS/`HTTP.sys` interfaces directly?

Comment: @Dai I more or less lifted that statement from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows and have run Python apps successfully using that approach (most recently, a dashboard site built with Plotly Dash (which is Flask under the hood). What is confusing is there is no mention of ANCM there, instead this doc recommendeds HttpPlatformHandler which is pretty much dead but ANCMv2 is basically the successor of it and you'll see the attributes there are the same, just swap out httpPlatform with aspNetCore

Comment: I have a .NET 5 website that runs happily with module "AspNetCoreModule". Why does that work?

Comment: @DeveloperWebs (I just spent the past 2 hours going through the old source-code for V1 of ANCM in order to answer your question) - apparently V1 functions _only_ as a very simple request proxy module, so it only supports ASP.NET Core applications in  out-of-process mode) - I'll admit that I'm surprised it works _at all_ (and it certainly isn't supported by MS). But by running V1 you're missing-out on the considerable performance and diagnostics benefits of running in-proc within `w3wp.exe`).

Comment: @DeveloperWebs For example, V1 isn't able to forward `ConnectionAborted` signals to out-of-process ASP.NET Core - so even though basic HTTP request/response handling will work, WebSockets too - but things like disconnect-notifications and HTTP/3 will not.